# How to constrain table-cell width and hide overflowing content

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to make a two column CSS table (tried HTML table too) with one row where the first column is one line of text and it expands to fit the content. The second column needs to be a single line of text that is right justified and expands left until it hits the first column and then becomes an ellipsis.

This first column is working with `white-space: nowrap;`. The second column is the issue:

When the content is longer than the second column max width, it will wrap. Once I add `white-space: nowrap;` it overflows and ignores the `width`, `max-width` and `overflow: hidden`;

Here is a JSFiddle showing what I'm getting vs. what I'm trying to get. Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/esodell1/oq59jkr3/10/

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the responses, but I found a way to accomplish this using flex box!

https://jsfiddle.net/esodell1/jdykzv5m/13/

Answer (score 2):

So this is how the text-overflow technique works. There needs to be a defined width of it's parent or a closest parent. You'll need to defined a width for your cell such as:

```
&:last-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 85%; 
  text-align: right;
}
```

But you'll also have to limit your table since table naturally tries to expand as much as the content in its child requires by using `table-layout`:

```
.table {
  display: table;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This will make the right column create the ellipsis when the cell reaches 85% of its available width. The problem you'll be faced with is dealing with the left column because you also have `no-wrap` set on it so that column might actually exceed 15% width and overlap with the right. The issue is both your column is trying not to wrap and fighting for table space, you'll need to apply the same `text-overflow` technique on the left column. See the the previous and last example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/bhL6sx0g/

To be honest if you're dealing with many columns with dynamic content like this that you don't want wrapping you might want to add a layer of JS on top to do some of your sizing for you else the best option is delegate the actual widths such as a 15/85 split and stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Give width units in `vw`(viewport width). Notice changes in scss of table(`width`), first-child( `width`, `min-width`) and last-child(`width`, `max-width`).

This `vw` will behaved strangely in jsfiddle, try in `.html` only.

```
.table {
  display: table;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  width:90vw;

  .row {
    display: table-row;

    .cell {
      display: table-cell;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      padding: 0.25rem;

      &:first-child {
        white-space: nowrap;
        width:20vw;
        min-width:20vw;
      }

      &:last-child {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 70vw;
        max-width: 70vw;
        text-align: right;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Previous**

By `max-width:100%` it can stretch to take full size of parent. You need limit it to some percentage or pixels to achieve desired effect.

Removed `width:100%` as it was useless and changed `max-width:200px`

```
&:last-child {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        /* width: 100%; */
        max-width: 200px;
        text-align: right;
      }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the parent in this case be the row, or even the table? I was just trying to make the right column expand to fill any available space, since I don't know the width of the lefthand side at the time